# QgisPlugin_Faculty

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

This is the formula for calculating stdev. My goal is to get raster but I'm getting a result in python console **[ ]** insted of raster.

```
formula_st = '((' + str(k) + '-2)/(' + str(k) + '-1)*C + (1/' + str(k) + ')*(A-B)*(A-B))'
st_dev_slope=processing.runalg('gdalogr:rastercalculator', average_slope, 1, slope_poc, 1, st_dev_poc, 1, None, 0, None, 0, None, 0, formula_st, '', 5, '0', None)
X = QgisRasterLayer(st_dev_slope['OUTPUT'])

QgisMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer([X])
```